# Книги по Java EE

Tags: java-ee, книги

Делаю проект (научная работа в ВУЗе) там связка апплет+сервлет, и частенько сталкиваюсь с проблемами, а когда нахожу решение в интернете, то не понимаю смысл некоторых операторов/частей кода (если там не расписано). Хочу все-таки "понять" java ee. С java в принципе работал, но веб-приложения (любые другие штуки связанные с Веб) никогда не разрабатывал.
Подскажите хорошие книги на русском языке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите книги:

*Java сервлеты и jsp,сборник рецептов*(автора не помню);

*Хорстман java2 том 2 тонкости прогграммирования*

Все эти книги есть в интернете,советую вам первую книгу,но во второй тоже есть материал

Comment: Ну а потом почитайте установка tomcat,установка eclipse for ee developers,и можете радоваться и кодить)

Answer (score 1):

Ещё есть книга называется "Философия Java" (автора не помню), не совсем уж прям про программирование для веб, но как учебник довольно хороша.